# What regex should i use for this split?

Tags: java, regex, split

I have this String:

```
" < 2, 3, 4 >"
```

and i want to split in order to have an array like this:

```
["2", "3", "4"]
```

The "<" character can have white-spaces in both sides or just one or neither. The same aplies for the commas. So i don't know what regex should i use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `String[] arr = new Scanner(" < 2, 3, 4 >").useDelimiter("[<, >]+").tokens().toArray(String[]::new); System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));`

Comment: Do the match `<\s*(\d+(?:\s*\,\s*\d+)*)\s*>`,  do the split on $1 `\s*,\s*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
string.replaceAll("(\\s|\\<|\\>)", "").split(",");
```

Output using posted string is: `["2", "3", "4"]`

Answer (score 0):

```regex
\s([0-9]+)(,?)
```

- '\s' matches whitespace
- '[0-9]' means numbers
- '+' means one or more

So you're matching: (any whitespace)(at least one number)(an optional comma)

Answer (score 0):

String[]Part=strSource.split(",");
Int[]arrInt= new Int[Part.length()]
For(into i=0;i<Parth.length();i++)
{
arrInt[i]=Integer.parseInt(Part[i]);
}

A Code like this would do the trick I guess.